# Google Apps Engine, Google Apps Script and Javascript

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps

I need to develop an Enterprise Application which will integrate and extend an ERP application that will be on Amazon Elastic Server.

What should be my standard language of choice? Google Drive enables me to use javascript, so does Google Sites.

But when I check something called "Google apps Engine" it gives me the option of Java, Python and Go (never heard of this one).

But no Javascript. Is there a consistency problem? Cant I work javascript all the way? Where will the code run, in the cloud? I have to upload the code, compiled or not? Is there an online IDE like in Javascript or should I use Eclipse or something like that.

Is there any reason for not using javscript for backend processing? It would be great to keep the same language for Google Drive, Sites, acessing the ERP through Webservices, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is used mainly for frontend development, that's why there is a Google Drive and Sites API for Javascript.
If you are going to develop something in a Google App Engine server, you will use Java, Go or Python.
The only way to use javascript in the server side, is to use something like node.js or any other implementation of javascript in the server, but this is not suported by Google App Engine as far as i know.